# gem 'ajax_pagination' vs jquery function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, pagination

After addition to will_paginate ajax_pagination гpdate on the check-box work only on first page.
_page.html.erb:

```
<%= ajax_links :section_id => "page" do %>
    <%= will_paginate @jquestions %>
<% end %>
<%= ajax_loadzone do %>
    <% @jquestions.each do |jquestion| %>
    <h2><%== (Dquestion.find(jquestion.dquestion_id)).question_text %> </h2> </br>
        <%= render (Janswer.where(jquestion_id: jquestion.id)) %>

    </br>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

janswers.js.coffee:

```
jQuery.fn.submitOnCheck = ->
    @find('input[type=checkbox]').click ->
        $(this).parent('form').submit()
        this

jQuery ->
    $('.edit_janswer').submitOnCheck()
```

and form:

```
<%= form_for(janswer, remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= f.check_box :truanswer %> <%== (Danswer.find(janswer.danswer_id)).answer_text  %>
<% end %>
```

How to decide this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you realy need ajax gem?

**Ryan Bates** show how to easy workaround:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax with few jquery code

I thought you are fully reaload page and dropp bindings. You have to reset them or use something like that:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'input[type=checkbox]', ()->
   //your stuff
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/ see description here